# How can I draw an angled wall with constant thickness per slice along an axis?

Tags: cad, solidworks

This questions is hard for me to formulate, so here is the problem:
During these Covid-19 times, my dad (a mechanics manufacturing teacher) made two articles ([1](https://mackid.legtux.org/?p=2339), [2](https://mackid.legtux.org/?p=2376)) on how to design and model custom-fit respiratory masks in SolidWorks in order to 3D print them (let’s not talk about the masks efficiency here, these were mostly made for fun, but are also probably better than nothing).

While 3D printing the 3 masks he designed, I noticed that the movements were sometimes a bit weirds and shaky on the main part (on the right in the Cura screenshot below), that is because even though the walls thickness is 0.8 mm (which corresponds to 2 times the nozzle diameter, so that it would just make two continuous perimeters per layer), because the walls aren’t straight but are at an angle, that means the layer slice is thicker the more the walls are angled.

[image: Mask in cura]

With a little bit of very simple maths (here with Pythagore), you can determine the thickness of the wall on one layer, here on the next picture with a 45° slope (the printed thickness of the wall is `x`, in red):

[image: Drawing of the problem]

Now, that is all good and logical, my question is: how can you design that kind of shape (made with splines and smoothing function) in a CAD software so that it has a constant thickness on each layer or slice of the model, here on the vertical axis? This would make the model much more 3D printing friendly.

I hope I am understandable, as I had a bit of trouble translating some names to French (CAD functions for example). Thanks!

Comment: If you want to print it exactly 2 perimeters thick everywhere, why not make the model solid, and print it with 2 perimeters, zero infill, and no top or bottom layers?

Comment: Also - N.B. that 0.8mm is likely not the best thickness - your line width is typically slightly wider than your nozzle diameter, and there is some overlap between the two layers. I use PrusaSlicer, which automatically calculates and recommends the optimum thickness based on your parameters - for their default profile it's 0.87mm for 2 lines, and 1.70 for 4 lines.

Comment: Thanks for your help, having a solid and setting the slicer like you said would make it work yes, although I hoped there was something to make it in the CAD software.
For thickness I don’t think Cura gives such informations, is it really that important if there is no infill regions? Like if it’s a bit smaller it will still make 2 perimeters when printing, right?

Comment: Sure, but the slicer will have to reduce the flow and the line width below its usual (and likely optimal) values in order to achieve this. Your line width should typically be a bit wider than your nozzle opening, and there is some overlap between perimeters.

Comment: Alright thanks, I thought Cura “rounded up” the thickness per layer when it was under the minimum perimeters number (no infill region) so that it was a multiple of the extrusion width..